# Need to update the csv file with the timestamp of the files from another location

Tags: shell, unix

I have a csv file score.csv with at path /NAS/DQ with 2 columns Scorename,filename.

```
scorename,filename
ABC,cust.txt
XYZ,bank.txt
```

These filescust.txt and bank.txt are placed at /NAS/files_path. There will be unique instance of each file placed at this path everyday.
I want to append the file timestamp from /NAS/files_path to /NAS/DQ csv file.

So the timestamp should be updated everytime to the csv file at /NAS/DQ location.
I am new to unix and currently looking for ways to do it.
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: And what is the timestamp? Current time, modification time of the file, something else?

Comment: Thanks Shawn for the correction. It's current time.

Answer (score 0):

Sed will be a good candidate for this:

```
 sed -ri '2,$s/(^.*$)/\1 '$(date)'/' filename
```

Substitute the existing line for the existing line plus a space and the date. The format of the date can be amended as required with +%.. We don't want to format the first line, so run the amendments from lines 2 to the last line ($)

Comment: Hi Raman,
Can you please help me understand the above code.

Comment: 2,$ means only process the 2nd line to the last line in the file. Then s signifies substitute. The section between the first / ./ is what we are searching for (in this case, the whole line from start of the line (^) to end of line ($). The section between the second / / signifies what we are substituting for. This is a space and then the output returned from date.

Comment: At which step we are matching the filename at both the locations and then picking the modification time?
I mean the filenames in the csv file at  /NAS/DQ has to be matched with the filename at NAS/files_path and the timestamp has to be picked from the NAS/files_path and updated in the csv file at /NAS/DQ in column number 3.
Sorry if my requirement wasn't clear.